Initialising a polars dataframe with 15 million records freezes the machine
I'm using Psycopg3 connector to fetch records from AWS RDS Posgres Database and i'm initialising Polars dataframe using the code below:
rds_conn = psycopg.connect(
        host=config.RDS_HOST_NAME,
        dbname=config.RDS_DB_NAME,
        user=config.RDS_DB_USER,
        password=config.RDS_DB_PASSWORD,
        port=config.RDS_PORT)
    cur = rds_conn.cursor(name="rds_cursor")
    cur.itersize = 100000
    cur.execute(sql_query)
    names = [x[0] for x in cur.description]
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    df = pl.DataFrame(rows, schema=names, infer_schema_length=None)

It works fine if the number of rows returned is around a million or so. Currently one of my table in RDS contains 15 million records and when i initialise the Polars dataframe, my machine freezes and i need to reboot my machine. I tried using LazyFrame over Dataframe but still the same.
Psycopg connector returns 15 million records without any issues but the problem happens when i initialise it as a Polars dataframe.
Is there a better way to do initialise my dataframe so that i don't have this issue? Can someone please help me on this?
Thanks

Get a bigger machine? You're fetching 15 million records into memory, and Polars will need to copy them to its own format, so you're likely ending up in some sort of swap hell. Alternately, stream the 15 million records into a disk format that Polars can read; or alternately, process the data into Polars frames in smaller chunks than 15M rows.

Don't use psycopg use the polars built in database connections here read_database: Both engines have native support for Apache Arrow and so can read data directly into a Polars DataFrame without copying the data.

Also this cur.itersize = 100000 is not doing what you think it is. When you do rows = cur.fetchall() you are materializing the entire result set(15 million rows). itersize will only work when iterating over the cursor e.g. for row in cur: print(row). In that case the server cursor will fetch 100000 rows at a time to send to the client.

@AdrianKlaver does polars read database support aws postgresql as i'm sure it supports non cloud version?

I don't have an AWS RDS instance to test against, but I am almost certain if you could reach it with the psycopg connection you can reach it with read_database_uri(). Try it and find out.

@AdrianKlaver  Perfect - polars.read_database_uri works like a charm in aws rds postgres - all it needs is to connectorx and i used the following syntax:
uri = "postgresql://user:password@rds-host-name:5432/dbname"
df = pl.read_database_uri(sql_query, uri)
Thank you so much for your help!

As suggested by AdrianKlaver in the above comment, I tried to fetch AWS RDS Postgres records using polars read_database_uri instead of psycopg3 and it worked perfectly without my machine hanging for 15 million records. Below are the steps:

Install connectorx

Syntax to fetch AWS RDS records:
uri="postgresql://RDS_DB_USER:RDS_DB_PASSWORD@RDS_HOST_NAME:RDS_PORT/RDS_DB_NAME"

df = pl.read_database_uri(sql_query, uri)



